# How to install ChatterBot successfully?

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, python-3.8, chatterbot

I tried `pip install ChatterBot` and ended up with error. I am using Python 3.8 64 bit rc1.
I do have installed all build tools. Please help me!
Here is the powershell snippet -

> Collecting ChatterBot   Using cached
>   ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB) Collecting
>   pymongo<4.0,>=3.3   Downloading pymongo-3.10.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
>   (355 kB)
>        |████████████████████████████████| 355 kB 78 kB/s Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2   Using cached nltk-3.5.zip (1.4 MB) Collecting
>   python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7   Using cached
>   python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB) Requirement
>   already satisfied: pytz in
>   c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
>   (from ChatterBot) (2020.1) Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1   Using cached
>   spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)   Installing build dependencies ... error
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
>   'c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe'
>   'c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip'
>   install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
>   'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h_upx5_5\overlay'
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython
>   'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0'
>   'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
>          cwd: None   Complete output (105 lines):   Collecting setuptools
>       Using cached setuptools-46.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (582 kB)   Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
>       Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)   Collecting Cython
>       Using cached Cython-0.29.17-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB)   Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
>       Using cached cymem-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (33 kB)   Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
>       Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)   Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
>       Using cached murmurhash-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (20 kB)   Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
>       Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)   Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
>       Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)   Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
>       Using cached wasabi-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)   Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
>       Downloading srsly-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (181 kB)   Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
>       Using cached numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (12.8 MB)   Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
>       Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)   Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
>       Using cached tqdm-4.46.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)   Building wheels for collected packages: preshed, thinc, blis
>       Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
>       Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
>       Created wheel for preshed: filename=preshed-2.0.1-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl size=73256
>   sha256=459c0e938c749929253676d80c906a5dfa1b6a6374fdda9bf585252581ea3dfb
>       Stored in directory: c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\5a\d0\29\7f6993a759349eae3d0ecca7e2fbc88acdd8650b25e6c6ad8a
>       Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): started
>       Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
>       Created wheel for thinc: filename=thinc-7.0.8-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl size=1961138
>   sha256=499dc0f5fd5961530ac32c787e92ff117e6f5c723853db28a783350490089483
>       Stored in directory: c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\f4\5b\cc\8a96be826c5d22ca28e3c30f785b22edc57ffb2d349fa780be
>       Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
>       Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
>       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: 'c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u
>   -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-c8gofksg'
>            cwd: C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\
>       Complete output (25 lines):
>       BLIS_COMPILER? None
>       running bdist_wheel
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       copying blis__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>       copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>       copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>       copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>       copying blis\tests__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>       copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       copying blis__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>       running build_ext
>       error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>       msvc
>       py_compiler msvc
>       {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:',
>   'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG':
>   'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME':
>   'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS':
>   '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL':
>   '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME':
>   'matt', 'PATH':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common
>   Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA
>   Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft
>   VS
>   Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \[\e]0;\u@\h:
>   \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
>   ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '|
>   /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
>       clang -c C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\blis_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c
>   -o C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4il6g9mr\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o
>   -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\blis_src\include\windows-x86_64
>       ----------------------------------------
>       ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
>       Running setup.py clean for blis   Successfully built preshed thinc   Failed to build blis   Installing collected packages: setuptools,
>   wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly,
>   plac, tqdm, thinc
>         Running setup.py install for blis: started
>         Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'
>         ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>          command: 'c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u
>   -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e10f22k2\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h_upx5_5\overlay'
>   --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h_upx5_5\overlay\Include\blis'
>              cwd: C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\
>         Complete output (25 lines):
>         BLIS_COMPILER? None
>         running install
>         running build
>         running build_py
>         creating build
>         creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
>         creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         copying blis__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>         copying blis\tests__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
>         copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         copying blis__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
>         running build_ext
>         error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>         msvc
>         py_compiler msvc
>         {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:',
>   'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG':
>   'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME':
>   'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS':
>   '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL':
>   '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME':
>   'matt', 'PATH':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common
>   Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA
>   Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft
>   VS
>   Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \[\e]0;\u@\h:
>   \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
>   ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '|
>   /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_':
>   '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
>         clang -c C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\blis_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c
>   -o C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnva1c606\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o
>   -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\blis_src\include\windows-x86_64
>         ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u
>   -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1sv2rk2\blis\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e10f22k2\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h_upx5_5\overlay'
>   --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h_upx5_5\overlay\Include\blis'
>   Check the logs for full command output.
>   ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe'
>   'c:\users\srpx3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip'
>   install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
>   'C:\Users\srpx3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h_upx5_5\overlay'
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython
>   'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0'
>   'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for
>   full command output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of pip install chatterbot, try pip install sugaroid-chatterbot.